# Get current time zone in IANA time zone format (a.k.a. Olson format)?

Tags: time-date

I know that `current-time-zone` can be called to obtain the current time zone. On my system, this returns `(-25200 "PDT")`. However, I would like to get the current time zone in IANA format, which for me would be `"America/Los_Angeles"`. Is there a way to do this from Emacs? On Unix-based systems, I can read the current target of the symlink `/etc/localtime`, as explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451925. However, is there a more Emacs-native way to do this?